# A question related to UIButton

Tags: iphone

I have taken customview in my code for UIButton.

```
UIButton *button=  [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain]; 
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkedimage:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(IBAction)checkedimage:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"checkedimage");

if(checkImage == NO)
{
    newImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];
    checkImage=YES;
}
else if(checkImage==YES)
{
    newImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
    checkImage=NO;
}
}
```

but  when i click on UIButton  it is   not   going to action  checkedimage
why?

Comment: You dont't add button in View and don't have frame of button so set all these thing..

Answer (score 1):

You have not set it up correctly and not really given us enough information to help you.

Have you anywhere in your code created an `IBOutlet` with the type of `UIButton` and name of `button`? If you have done that have you in IB assign that IBOutlet to the correct UIButton?
If you have done that as well you really should not declare a NEW UIButton in the code with the same name. It should already exist as a property in the current class you are working in.

If you have not done any of the above you need to ADD your newly created button to a view somewhere for it to be visible at all.

I advise you to read some basic tutorials on how to use IB.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Have you added this button to the view?  Using interface builder?

I ran this test code based on what you sent, all works just fine:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
UIButton *button= [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkedimage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 120, 20);
[self.view addSubview:button];
}

 -(IBAction)checkedimage:(id)sender { 
 NSLog(@"checkedimage");
}
```